# Want to Convert decimal value in 2 raised to format and want to know its power of 2 in java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have one decimal value like `65` and I want to divide this value in 2 raised to format.

For example, I have this type rule:

[image]

If I get `42` as a decimal number, I want to divide first `42 number in format of 2 raised to`. Then, I want to output its power only, like:

```
OutPut : 1,3,5
```

[image]

For example, if I have 65 as a decimal number, then I want `6,0` as its output, because (2 raised to 6) + (2 raised to 0) = 65.

Thanks

Anybody can help me how I can achieve this thing in Java.

Comment: bitwise operators are your friends

Comment: @Rohit jain i want way how can i do

Comment: 2^1 is 2, not 1, so the output for 65 should be 6,0 - not 6,1

Comment: @Alnitak sorry my mistake i updated my question

Comment: What does '2 raised to format' mean?

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeatedly compare the least significant bit, counting as you go, and right-shifting the number to look at each bit in turn:

```
int n = 65
int d = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    if ((n & 1) == 1) {  // check LSB
        System.out.println(d);
    }
    n >>>= 1;  // shift right
    ++d;       // inc digit count
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer.toString(65, 2);
```

Does the following output:

```
1000001
```

Then you work on the String.

Comment: and `System.out.println(Integer.toString(42, 2);` gives 101010.  Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

This can be improved, but I think it'll do the job.

```
int n = 42;
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    for(int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')
            System.out.print(i+1);      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the algorithm:

1. Find a log base 2 of given number x=log(2, input)
2. Find the floor and the ceiling of the result  y = floor(x), z=ceiling(x)
3. Find 2^y, 2^z and choose the one closer to the input.
4. calculate the diff = (input - 2^(x or y)) and do the same for the diff recursively until dif=0.